# How do I install the 3.2 or the 3.3 kernels in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, kernel

I have a Aspire One A0751h net-book that uses the EMGD 1.10 driver and at the moment i'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with Kernel 3.0.0-17-generic.

But i was wondering if i could upgrade the Kernel to 3.2 or 3.3 and have it fully working. I had tried to install Kernel 3.2 RC4 but it didn't boot. I'm still new to Linux so i might have done it work. Any comment or links to instructions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I downloaded

```
linux-headers-3.2.0-030200rc4-generic_3.2.0-030200rc4.201112012035_i386.deb 
linux-headers-3.2.0-030200rc4_3.2.0-030200rc4.201112012035_all.deb  
linux-image-3.2.0-030200rc4-generic_3.2.0-030200rc4.201112012035_i386.deb
```

from this link kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-rc4-oneiric then i used gdeb package installer to install the 3 files using the instructions found on this site http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=40185

I know Ubuntu 12.04 Uses Kernel 3.2 but default but there is no 3D available for my card (gma500) on 12.04

Comment: By the way, Ubuntu 12.04 has a mostly working 2D driver for Poulsbo, but I don't think there are 3D drivers for it yet. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo

Comment: you can install the newest kernel but you will have to apply the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware Support Components Video Cards Poulsbo

Open a terminal and add the repository, run the update, install the support and configure, then reboot.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gma500/emgd110
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emgd-support
sudo emgd-xorg-conf
```

EMGD Known Workarounds

Known workarounds that address problems such as Plymouth (startup screen), Brightness keys, Hibernate/Suspend, and Mplayer can be found on this page:

https://answers.launchpad.net/emgd/+faq/1450

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I already have EMGGD 1.10 installed. I want to know if its possible to update my Ubuntu 11.10 Kernel to 3.2 or 3.3 and have it work with EMGD

Comment: apparently, as I read the question, you had already downloaded the new kernel and applied the installation therefore the workaround would need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble's EMGD.  No, emgd-dkms package fails to build with 3.2 kernel.  (dkms packages take care of rebuilding "extra" kernel modules when your kernel is updated.)

I would just check this site every so often, that's where the info will pop up if/when 12.04 works with emgd.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo

In short though it looks like for now to get to 12.04 you do get dropped to a 2d and xv only driver.  I'm running 11.04 w/ emgd-1.8 right now for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you have EMGD 1.10 and going to dist-upgrade your system then,

please remove EMGD and remove /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10_emgd.conf generated by emgd-conf

Wrong xorg file won't make your system booted with X.

EDID checksum error happens anyway and can't be fixed.